# Get matched regexp from replace in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

My aim is to wrap any content in quotes in a div with specific id.

For example, if I've got a this string:

```
Bananas are "green", "pineapples" are blue.
```

I want to get this:

```
Bananas are <div id="mydivname">"green"</div>, <div id="mydivname">"pineapples"</div> are blue.
```

The  problem is that I don't know what exactly will be in brackets and it doesn't matter, I just want it to be wrapped right in the string.

I came up with a code like this:

```
var string = $('#somediv').html().replace(/\".*?\"/g,'<div id="mydivname">' + regexp + '</code>');
$('#somediv').html(string)
```

My problem is that I can't get the regexp for this element, I can just replace with some value, but I want to wrap it in `<div>`'s.

How di get the matched regExp from .replace to use it as replaceText?

Comment: Aside: You'd have to use classes instead of IDs for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use references to capturing groups

```
$('#somediv').html().replace(/(".*?")/g, '<div class="foo">$1</div>');
```

Or a replacement function:

```
$('#somediv').html().replace(/".*?"/g, function(match) {
    return '<div class="foo">' + match + '</div>';
});
```

Be careful with replacing stuff in the HTML. This will break children of `#somediv` with quoted attributes.

If you can, use `.text()` instead of `.html()` or iterate over text nodes with this replacement function.

Comment: *"Be careful with replacing stuff in the HTML. This will break children of #somediv with quoted attributes."* Indeed. You could minimize that risk by only processing the text in text nodes, and using the regex `/"[^"]+"/`... I think I'd be pretty reluctant to do that without narrowing the focus in those ways.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly for me. But what do I do if I want to wrap anything in `<!-- some text -->` instead of quotes?

Comment: @Timbo_KZ: Try figuring it out.

Comment: @Blender: I did, but it just doesn't work. I tried to escape the string `<\!--\.*?\--\>` in all possible ways but it just seem to have no effect.